# Can I use ROC/AUC to compare binomial GLMM models?

Tags: r, binomial-distribution, glmm, roc

Is there any reason not to use ROC for evaluating the effectiveness of a binomial GLMM model with logit link? In my specific case, I have six models (one null model with two random effects, five other models with one fixed effect and two random effects) and I want to compare them all using an easily understandable metric like AUC.

Comment: The only part of this that strikes me as tricky is deciding whether you're going to calculate predicted probabilities with or without the random effects, i.e. whether you're trying to get good predictions at the population level or the individual-group level ...

Comment: @BenBolker do you care to expand on that?

Comment: AUC is a very insensitive metric for model selection.  I wouldn't recommend using it for model selection, neither would Frank Harrell (see section 8.8 here https://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf)